# What is really happening in this code?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I have a code which includes a recursive function. I have wasted a lot of time on recursion but I still couldn't get it really:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void count(int);

int main()
{
    int x=10,z;
    count(x);
}

void count(int m)
{
    if(m>0)
        count(m-1);
    printf("%d",m);
}
```

When the 1st time `count` is called with argument as 10. it fulfills the condition and then here starts the recursive part. what happens really when a function calls itself? I don't get it. Please explain with reference to stacks.

Comment: please explain with reference to stacks

Comment: It just "starts" again, with the new parameter. It's just like a call to any other function. Try to write down the execution steps on a paper to see what happens. With smaller number, for example with 3.

Comment: @Let_me_be - why did you make stylistic changes to the code in the question? (It also happens to hide some undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 31):

While `m` is greater than 0, we call `count`. Here is a representation of the stack calls:

```
 count (m = 10)  
   count (m = 9)  
     count (m = 8)  
       count (m = 7)  
         count (m = 6)    
           count (m = 5)     
             count (m = 4)     
               count (m = 3)     
                 count (m = 2)     
                   count (m = 1)
                     count (m = 0)
                     printf 0
                   printf 1
                 printf 2
               printf 3
             printf 4
           printf 5
         printf 6
       printf 7
     printf 8
   printf 9
 printf 10
```

Answer (score 2):

next time it calls itself it has a smaller value

```
count(int m)
{
 if(m>0)
 count(m-1); // now it is calling the method "count" again, except m is one less
 printf("%d",m);
}
```

So first it will call count with 10, then it will call it with 9, then 8, then 7..... all the way until this if statement isn't true:

```
if(m>0)
```

What might be confusing you is the if statement only applies to the next line (printf isn't part of the if statement)

so you have:

```
count(int m)
    {
     if(m>0)
     {
         count(m-1); // now it is calling the method "count" again, except m is one less
     }
     printf("%d",m);
    }
```

So, the recursive calls will stop once m is not > 0, and then it will call the printf.

After it calls printf for when m is 0, then it will return from that 'count' call, (Back to where m was equal to 1), and then it will call the printf when m is 1, and then when m is 2, .....

So the output should be:

```
"0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"
```

EDIT:
In terms of a stack:

This is what the stack is doing:

```
count(10) // push count(10)
```

->

```
count(9) // push count(9)
count (10)
```

->

...

->

```
count(0) // push count(0)
count(1)
count(2)
count(3)
count(4)
count(5)
count(6)
count(7)
count(8)
count(9)
count(10)
```

-> (and then it starts printing and popping the method off the stack)

```
// pop count(0), and printf(0)
count(1)
count(2)
count(3)
count(4)
count(5)
count(6)
count(7)
count(8)
count(9)
count(10)
```

->

```
// pop count(1), and printf(1)
count(2)
count(3)
count(4)
count(5)
count(6)
count(7)
count(8)
count(9)
count(10)
```

->

...

->

```
// pop count(9), and printf(9)
count(10)
```

->

```
// pop count(10), and printf(10)
```

Comment: now that i see it is a homework tag. (and you are asking about stacks).
Do you have a basic understanding of stacks?

Comment: Each time "count" is called, it is being pushed onto the stack. Once the last "count" is called, it then calls "printf" and that count call is popped off the stack.


Ill try to show that on my answer

Answer (score 0):

When a function is called the return address (of the next code to execute) is stored on the stack along with its current arguments. Once the function finishes the address and arguments are popped so the cpu will know where to continue its code execution.

Let's write the addresses of the function (for the purpose of this example only)

```
count(int m)
{
(address = 100)  if(m>0)
(address = 101)     count(m-1); // now it is calling the method "count" again, except m is one less
(address = 102)  printf("%d",m);
}
```

For m = 1:

The `if` is fullfield so we execute code at `address 101` with `m = 1`. `address 102` and `m = 1` are pushed to the stack and the function is executed again from `address 100` with `m = 0`. Since `m = 0` we execute `address 102` and printing 0 on console. The function ends and the last return `address (102)` and argument `m = 1` are popped and the line at `address 102` is executed printing 1 on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

1. The function `count` is called with an integer argument of `10`.
2. Since the function argument `m` which is `10` is greater than `0` the function `count` calls itself with an integer argument of `m` which is `10` minus `1` which equals `9`.
3. Step 2 repeats with varying arguments `(m-1)` until `m` is not greater than `0` and which point the program prints the value of `m`.

The recursive function just modifies the parameter given to it and calls itself with that modified value until the desired result is returned (in this case `m` not being greater than `0`).

Answer (score 0):

Each number refers to the line number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
count(int);
main()
{
1int x=10,z;
2count(x);
}  
count(int m)
{
3if(m>0)
4   count(m-1);
5printf("%d",m);
}
```

The execution happens like this(with x=3) -

line number|value of x

1 3

2 3

3 3

4 2

3 2

4 1

3 1

4 0

5 0

5 1

5 2

5 3

Numbers printed on the screen 0 1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more specific answer, then you have to look into how compilers work. But generally speaking the compiler will create machine code for the function that includes a preamble, in this code enough memory is allocated on the stack (by decrementing a stack pointer) that a copy of the functions variables can be placed on the stack (we can store the state of the function).

The function will have values stored in registers and memory and these must be stored on the stack for each (recursive) call, otherwise the new call will overwrite the precious data!. So very basically the machine code looks like this (pseudo code)

```
//store m on the stack 
store m,stack_pntr+m_offset
//put input values in designated register
a0 = m
//allocate memory on the stack
stackPntr -= stack_size_of(count_vars)
//store return address in allocated register
//jump to the first instruction of count
.
.
```

By changing some data used for computation we can go back and read the same instructions again and get a different result. The abstraction of recursive function allows us to manipulate the data we want to change in a nice "call by value" way so that we don't overwrite it unintentionally.

This is done by the compiler when it stores the state of the calling function on the stack so we don't have to manually store it.