# This code is giving an absurd answer

Tags: c, function, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is really happening in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265477/what-is-really-happening-in-this-code)

I have a code which includes a recursive function. I have wasted a lot of time on recursion, but i still couldn't get it, really:

```
#include<stdio.h>

count(int);

 main(){
   int x=10,z;
   z=count(x);
}  
count(int m){
   if(m>0)
      return count(m-1);
}
```

When `count` is called for the first time with argument `10`, it fulfils the condition and the recursion starts. What happens really when a function calls itself? I dont get it. What does the statement `return count(m-1)` mean? Where does it tranfer the control?

Comment: Draw it out on paper with the function inlined. You also haven't expanded at all on the "absurd answer". What's absurd about it? What is it?

Comment: i know the meaning of `return` but i cant get it in recursive manner

Comment: i want the nos from 0-10 to be printed but it prints 9939 like the values

Comment: Your code doesn't print anything at all, so I'm not sure why you expect numbers to be printed.

Comment: Would you understand it if instead of calling 'count' inside 'count', it would call a different function? It's exactly the same, only it happens to call itself.

Comment: What should `count` return when m == 0?

Comment: This won't actually return anything, ever.

Answer (score 5):

The return value of the function `count` is undefined, because there is no default return if `(m <= 0)` is true.

> **C11, § 6.9.1 Function definitions**
>
> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the
>   function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Besides, to understand how a recursive function works, you have to take a paper and try to execute the code by yourself (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265477/what-is-really-happening-in-this-code)).

Answer (score 1):

You need `count` to return something when `m <= 0`.  You should declare the return type of `count` and compile with `-Wall` so the compiler will help you find mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

*recursion* means that the function will call itself, mostly at the end of itself, if it's tail recursion.

So your count function checks that the input argument is > 0 and then if it is, it will call `count(m-1)`.  Now it starts at the top of `count`  with m=9.  It does the same thing, and then calls count with m=8, etc.

Until the end condition is reached, which should normally be explicitly catered for in your function, such as `if (m == 0) return m;`  or some such thing.  At that point the recursion ends and the function terminates.

Also, `count`  should have a return type, such as `int count (int m)`

Answer (score 0):

> what does the statement return count(m-1) mean ? where does it tranfer the control?

That seems to be your only question.

it means that it is calling "count" with the value m-1.  So if m was 10, then it is calling "count" with 9.

It is transferring the control recursively to the count method.

You also don't have a return for the every possible path in the "count" method.
What happens if m is <= 0?