# How recursion works in this code?

Tags: c, function, recursion, stack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is really happening in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265477/what-is-really-happening-in-this-code)

in this problem i cant apply my concepts of recursion

```
#include<stdio.h>
count(int); 
main()
{
  int x=4;
  count(x);
  return 0;
 }
 count(int n)
 {
   if(n>0)
   { 
     count(n-1);
     printf("%d",n);
     count(n-1);
   }
  }
```

when we run the program `count(4),count(3),count.....count(0)` is stored in stack...but when `count(0)` is called and the `if` condition is false..then where does the control go?  please if anyone can explain with the help of a diagram showing various function calls.

Comment: @asawyer sure it is. Very old, bad C, but still C.

Comment: You have posted the same question at least 10 times in the last week.

Comment: can c functions have implicit return types?

Comment: @Flexo Well I'll be. I did not know you could omit things like that.

Comment: @king but i am still unable to get the answer

Comment: @user1648810 whilst it may be valid it most certainly is not modern idiomatic C.

Comment: @asawyer `typedef int;` is legal C :)

Comment: [Doesn't this answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265477/what-is-really-happening-in-this-code). Then why create new user ids and ask again? Ask for clarification there itself if you don't get your answer!

Comment: @Andreas Henning If I'm not mistaken, C functions return int by default.

Comment: @Flexo awww... I shouldn't do quick&dirty edits x_x thanks for pointing it out though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try the following piece of code.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
count(int);  
int  main() 
{ 
    int x=4; 
    count(x); 
    return 0; 
} 

int count(int n) 
{ 
    if(n>0) 
    {  
        printf("%d",n); 
        return count(n-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d",n); 
        return n; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ok I might have been fooled before, that surely this is not valid syntax!

Comment: Please do check the syntax yourself as i am not a c programmer. I have just given the logic for using recursion in this short program.

Comment: @asawyer - it's invalid here but only the typo of `}` instead of `{` after the else. It's weird to declare `count` with an implicit int and define with explicit return type though.

Comment: Thanks Fleox for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a diagram. With `count(0)`, the `if` statement fails, and `count` returns immediately without doing anything.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Flexo for pointing out that the program in its original form is UB, since there's no telling what a function declared to return int will do when it doesn't return anything. (In practice, I'm guessing that most calling conventions will behave innocuously, but it's still wrong, of course.)

Comment: Note that `count` is assumed to return `int`, but is missing a return, so it's UB.

Comment: it doesent matter whether there is a `return` statement or not

Comment: @user1648810 yes it does. Since you've not said otherwise the function is assumed to return an `int`. Not returning where something is expected is undefined behaviour.

Comment: the ans with `x=3` is `1213121`

Comment: @user1648810: You're missing Flexo's point. Undefined behaviour doesn't mean the program will crash. It means that you can't assume anything about how the program will behave. If you got the answer you expected, then you got lucky. The next compiler might take exactly the same program and crash, or it might yield the wrong answer, or it might hack your bank account and send me all your money.

Comment: @MarceloCantos - it might not need a change of compiler, it could behave differently on subsequent runs with the same output from the same compiler. I'd argue that it's *unlucky* if you have undefined behaviour that goes unnoticed rather than lucky :)

Comment: so it means this code is compiler dependent or wrong or this type of coding is obselete

Comment: @user1648810: Undefined behaviour means you've shot an arrow straight up in the air, and you're hoping it won't come straight back down. Whether you call that "living life on the edge" or "wrong" depends on your point of view, I suppose. I side with "wrong".